# Heroku error after deploying (No module named '_tkinter')

Tags: python, django, heroku, pyppeteer

I have an web app deployed on heroku (using Python), I am using now Pyppeteer to make some automatic jobs in a web site. After deploying I am getting this issue:

```
Request Method: GET
3.1.4   
ModuleNotFoundError 
No module named '_tkinter'  
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/tkinter/init.py, line 36, in  
/app/.heroku/python/bin/python  
3.6.12  
['/app/.heroku/python/bin', '/app', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Anyone faced this issue?
I already used the buildpacks for chrome and puppeteer but getting same error.
Also have tried:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You aren't going to be able to run tkinter on heroku. Tkinter requires a display and can't run on a server.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.6 includes the tkinter Python code, but not the library binary.

```
sudo apt install python3.6-tk
```